# Fixed navigation jumping on when -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;

Tags: html, ios, css, webkit

This only happens on Safari on IOS

I've applied

```
body {
    font-family: helvetica, verdana, sans-serif;
    background: #fff;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 100%;
    overflow-y: scroll; /* I added this */
    -webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch; /* and also this */
}
```

This is because i wanted to get smooth scrolling on mobile (Safari on IOS). But after doing that i've introduced a new bug, my navigation now is not fixed when i scroll. It jumps around and updates its location after the scrolling stops.

Here's the css for the navigation

```
.nav-bar {
    background-color: #ff0000;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 51px;
    z-index: 1030;
    max-height: 51px;
}

.nav-container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    height: 51px;
    max-width: 1170px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

THe html is

```
<body class="home">

    <div class="nav-bar">

        <div class="nav-container">

        </div>

    </div>

    <div class="content">
        <p>content here</p>
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Did you find a solution? I'm also having a similar issue